# update field based on entity id before saving

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have field in entity that should be calculated using id. I tried to solve this issue this way:

```
/**
 * Resources
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="resources")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyTask\Core\Repository\ResourcesRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Resources extends BaseEntity
{
...


    /**
     * @return $this
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     */
    public function generateHash()
    {
        $this->setHash(substr(md5($this->getId() . $this->getName()), 0, 8));
        return $this;
    }
```

But hash field is not calculated and remains null. Could you please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you included the @HasLifecycleCallbacks annotation for the class?

Comment: I added HasLifecycleCallbacks and I checked using break point this method was executed.

Comment: PrePersist was used earlier but id is null in this case and hash is not unique, but in PrePersist id is accessible.

Comment: Try adding the following parameter "LifecycleEventArgs $a" to generateHash. Then call $a->getEntity()->getId() and use that id to create the hash.

Comment: id is accessible in prePersisist as far as I can judge.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used php uniqid instead of using id of entity as I couldn't solve it using events.